# Find crashes when nothing is found

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with a list of course names called `Matrix`. In another sheet named `Courses Date` I will have the same courses with the date they were taken.

## Example:

The course named `Safety Driving` will be in `Matrix` on row 1. In `Courses Date` there is data from `E1:BF1` with the same name. If courses need a refreshment there will be another column named exactly the same name of the course + `Refresher` (`Safety Driving Refresher`).

What I am trying to do is to find if a course has a refresher or not. My code returns **Run-time error '91':** `Object variable or With block variable not set` if nothing is found.

This is my code:

```
RefresherColNumber = Range("'Courses Date'!E1:BF1").Find(Range("'Matrix'!" & courseColLetter & "1").Value & " Refresher").Column
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a check

```
Dim refreshRange As Range 

Set refreshRange = Range("'Courses Date'!E1:BF1").Find(Range("'Matrix'!" & courseColLetter & "1").Value & " Refresher")

If Not refreshRange Is Nothing Then RefresherColNumber = refreshRange.Column
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Application.Match` to test, with IsError, if value found in row and add 4 to where found to get the column.  You should qualify your ranges with the parent worksheet object as well to avoid bugs with implicit activesheet referencing.

```
Dim matchValue As Variant
matchValue = Application.Match(Range("'Matrix'!" & courseColLetter & "1").Value & " Refresher", Range("'Courses Date'!E1:BF1"), 0)

If Not IsError(matchValue) Then RefresherColNumber = matchValue + 4
```

Comment: why matchValue + 4?

Comment: Because the actual column start is E but Match will return one for E in the given range. So you need to add 4 to get the actual column number of any number returned by Match.

Comment: it shows error `Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed`

Comment: Have you verified that your range constructions in the _Range("'Matrix'!" & courseColLetter & "1"_ and _Range("'Courses Date'!E1:BF1")_  are correct? I suspect there is an error in there somewhere.

Comment: When the error occurs, Ctrl + G to open the immediate window and type ?Range("'Matrix'!" & courseColLetter & "1").Address, then repeat that for ?Range("'Courses Date'!E1:BF1").Address. Same error message for one of them?