# Find cell and copy formatting stopped working

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, find

I have a simple spreadsheet with a list of dates and entries in one sheet and a calendar on another sheet. When I first created it, I put together the following code to find the calendar date from sheet 1 and copy the conditional formatting I had set in sheet 1 into the cells in the calendar. It worked fine until I added more entries to sheet 1 then all of a sudden I get a Run-time error '91' and I can't for the life of me see why it has stopped working. I am new to coding so there is probably something obvious I am missing.

Here is what I have so far

```
Sub find_and_paste_formatting()
    'On Error Resume Next (had to remove when it stopped working to find the error)'

    Dim Date_Row As Long
    Dim Date_Col As Long

    'Sheet with dates to use in find
    Table1 = Sheet2.Range("A5:G5").Cells
    
    'The cell from where you need to start populating the formatting
    Date_Row = Sheet2.Range("A6").Row
    Date_Col = Sheet2.Range("A6").Column

    For Each cl In Table1
        'Just a test to see if it returns the correct cell reference
        Sheet2.Cells(Date_Row, Date_Col) = Sheet1.Range("A1:D20").Find(cl, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlRows).Address

        'change the formatting to match the sheet 1 conditional formatting
        Sheet2.Cells(Date_Row, Date_Col).Interior.ColorIndex = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Range("A1:D20").Find(cl, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlRows).Address).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
    
        Date_Col = Date_Col + 1    
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: It **really** helps to declare _all_ your variables - since you're looping through `Table1` you should be using the `Set` statement when assigning a value to it (and declare `cl` as a `Range`).

Comment: Error 91 happens when Find doesn't find anything, and you try to use the output of the Fing.  [See here for the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52385310)

Comment: Thanks @SpectralInstance, I followed your advice but still get hit by the same error. The bit that I don't get is that it worked fine, I can recreate worksheets with data and run the code in them and it works, but at some point it just stops working and I get the error telling me it cant find anything.

Comment: Since you are trying to find on a _specific_ sheet, your _After_ parameter should be `After:=Sheet1.Range("A1")` - if you don't want to use error trapping to accommodate 'nothing being found' then you can use the `COUNTIF` worksheet function to first check if the sought value exists in the range and, only after that returns a non-zero result, do the actual `Find`

Answer (score 0):

I got mad and took another crack at it from a different angle. There was something about  finding dates that was the issue. Came across this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639660/range-find-on-a-date-that-is-a-formula] and everything works perfectly. Thanks for the help @SpectralInstance

```
Sub Find_dates_copy_formatting()
    
    Dim findDate As Date
    Dim R As Range
    Dim C As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    

Set WS = Worksheets(1)
Set R = WS.Range("C1:C261")

For m = 1 To 52

For n = 2 To 6


findDate = Sheet2.Cells(3 * m - 1, n).Value

For Each C In R
    If C.Value2 = CDbl(findDate) Then
    Sheet2.Cells(3 * m, n).Interior.ColorIndex = C.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
    Sheet2.Cells(3 * m + 1, n).Interior.ColorIndex = C.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex

End If
Next C

Next n
Next m

End Sub
```